# Solving a system with tensor quantities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

I have an equation that involves

$\sum_{abcd} x_ax_bx_cx_d M^{abcd}+\sum_{ab}x_ax_bN^{ab}=0$ where M, N are known.

M has the property that $M^{abcd}=M^{cdab}$. N is symmetric in its indices.

I would like to do something like this (although I think it is not formal):

Define matrix $X$ with elements $X_{ab} \equiv x_a x_b$. Unpack elements in a vector $\vec{X}$ so that I have indices $\alpha \equiv (ab)$.

Now write $M^{abcd}\equiv \mathcal{M}^{\alpha\beta}$. In some sense I am defining a matrix from a tensor like quantity.

Finally I pack $N^{ab}$ in a vector $\vec{N}$ with elements $N_{\alpha}$.

Now my equation becomes:

$\vec{x}^T\mathcal{M}\vec{x}+\vec{x}^T\vec{N}=0\ (1)$

(I also have some extra condition on this, but for the sake of the question I omit it as I am interested in this part)

First question:

- Is equation (1) legitimate? I feel that if I unpack everything I should reobtain the initial equation.

Second question:

- Does it make sense to take the inverse of this matrix coming from a tensor?

Sorry for this naive questions, I've never encountered a problem like this and wanted to make sure these operation would make sense.

Comment: Just to clarify: is $x$ meant to be a vector (i.e. it has only one index)?

Comment: Yes, x is just a vector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that everything here is completely legitimate. If you'd like to connect to existing techniques and terminology, what you are doing to the vectors $X$ and $M$ is called [tensor reshaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_reshaping) (or more specifically, vectorization and matricization).

Following the notation of the linked article: suppose that $M$ has size $n \times n \times n \times n$, and $N$ has size $n \times n$. If $\mu:[n] \times [n] \to [n^2]$ is a bijection, then
$$
\vec x_{\mu(a,b)} = X_{ab} = x_ax_b, \quad \mathcal M^{\mu(a,b)\mu(c,d)}= M^{abcd}, \quad \vec N_{\mu(a,b)} = N^{ab}.
$$
In terms of some other notation: if the standard (lexicographical) choice of $\mu$ is taken, then the resulting $X$ can be written as $X = (x \otimes x)(x \otimes x)^T$, where $x$ is a column-vector, $T$ denotes a transpose, and $\otimes$ denotes a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Regarding your second question: it makes sense to take the inverse of $\mathcal M$ (assuming this inverse exists) in the same way that it makes sense to take the inverse of any square matrix. It is unclear, however, whether there is any meaningful connection to be made between the resulting inverse $\mathcal M^{-1}$ and the original tensor $M$.

Comment: Thanks @Omnomnomnom! To connect $\mathcal{M}^{-1}$ to the original tensor $M$ I would just take the elements of $M$ no? My question to you is this: is it then meaningful to solve for $\vec{x}$ in terms of $\mathcal{M}^{-1}$? Suppose $(1)$ is a function, not just an equation, that I want to minimize. Then I would imagine that I could take a derivative and solve for $\vec{x}$. Is this makes sense, then problem solved!

Comment: @Saladino If we want to minimize the original quantity $\sum_{abcd} x_ax_bx_cx_d M^{abcd}+\sum_{ab}x_ax_bN^{ab}$, then the equivalent formulation in terms of your reshaped tensors is
$$
\min \vec x^T \mathcal M \vec x + \vec x^T \vec N \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \vec x = x \otimes x, x \in \Bbb R^n.
$$
Because $\vec x$ has a certain "low rank structure", we can't simply minimize the quadratic form in the usual way.

Comment: @Saladino I suspect that it would still be useful to rewrite this objective function in the form $(\vec x - \vec b)^T \mathcal M (\vec x - \vec b)$

Comment: so it is impossibile to solve for this? Even if you had a constraint?

Comment: Imagine I have $\vec{x}^T\mathcal{M}\vec{x}+\vec{x}^T\vec{N}$ with $\vec{x}^T\vec{c}=1$, where $\vec{c}$ is a known vector. Do you know non standard ways to optimize? Numerically I would guess something like netwon-raphson(even with the original form). I am curious analitically!

Comment: Also I did not understand this "low rank structure"... like not enough degrees of freedom?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "solve for this".  Regarding "low rank structure", I'm referring to the fact that if we "unvectorize" $\vec x$, then the resulting matrix $X$ has rank $1$.

Comment: Solve for this I mean obtain numerical values for each element of $\vec{x}$. Do you know some notes please I could study to understand how to solve such systems?

Comment: @Saladino In that case you could probably do some sort of gradient descent at least. I don't have any such notes to offer.

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion! So no analytical solution then